# Center items in listview vertically

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, the listviews width and height should be set to match parent. So, if the listview is fully stretched and has only 2 items in it, they are at the top of the listview and on the bottom is too much useless space. I want to know, if it is possible to center these 2 items in this listview vertically, if yes, how?

Comment: you can do it by changing listview width and height to wrap content, put your listView inside another layout and center it.
something like this:

<RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/mylist"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: I would recommend putting your ListView in a RelativeLayout and set android:layout_centerInParent="true" for the ListView. Then once the ListView is created check to see if it fills the entire screen and if not set the layout params to `new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` for your ListView. That would center your ListView in the container. I `WOULD NOT` set your ListView to wrap content by default. If you ever have a long list that will not make your app happy.

Comment: thanks for replies, i will use wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List height depends on the height of the list item, that is populating the list.
If you have only two items in the list why don't you simply use a Linear Layout instead with weightSum?

Anyway, if you want to achieve the result you requested in your question you have to get the display height using method

`getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels` in activity context.

After that you need to set the height of the list item to the height you retrieved earlier divided by 2.
And also set gravity to center_vertical for the textviews in the list.